# .net core angular 2 css not found

Tags: css, angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core Template Pack (Angular 2 , Net core ,webpack) ([plugin website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack))

Now I need to use a css file that is not located in mycomponents folder.

**My folder structure :**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhBwT.jpg)

Component

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./mystyle.css')]
 
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

and I ran the command :

> > webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js

I still get the error

> Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "./mystyle.css"

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css file is located in different folder.

Path to your custom css should be `[require('../../../assets/css/mystyle.css')]`

Please note it that there is already created css file for `app.component` by default.

Comment: I want use a global css file. Thanks for the answer !